# How can I change the lite mode to dark mode according to the user's time?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vanillajs-datepicker

How can I change the lite mode to dark mode according to the user's time using JS ?
`

```
// function to set a given theme/color-scheme
  function setTheme(themeName) {
     localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
     document.documentElement.className = themeName;
}
// function to toggle between light and dark theme
function toggleTheme() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
     setTheme('theme-light');
  } else {
     setTheme('theme-dark');
  }
}
// Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
(function () {
  if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
     setTheme('theme-dark');
     document.getElementById('dark-light-mode').checked = false;
 } else {
     setTheme('theme-light');
     document.getElementById('dark-light-mode').checked = true;
 }
})();
```

`

`

```
   <label id="switch" class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleTheme()" id="dark-light-mode">
     <span class="slider round"></span>
   </label>
```

`

I wanna change theme between light and dark via user's time

Comment: You could create an [interval function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) that checks the time every minute or so.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and apply theme according to the selected time

You can do something like this.

```js
 let hour = (new Date).getHours();

  if (hour >= 18) {
     setTheme('theme-dark');
  } else {
     setTheme('theme-light');
  }
```

It will apply dark theme if the time is greater then 18

You would also need `setInterval` so it will watch the time and fire event based on the condition.